# dyanamically creating directories with pam_mkhomedir and mysql for vsftpd

Tags: linux, pam, vsftpd

I've installed vsftpd using the following instructions

http://www.camcloud.com/blog/setup-vsftpd-with-virtual-users-using-mysql

I'm trying to automatically/dynamically create directories for each user as they log into the ftp server.

I have the following `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` which *does not* automatically create the directory.

**Static Directory Configuration Code**

```
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke 
auth       required     pam_mysql.so      verbose=1 user=mydbusername passwd=mydbpass host=localhost db=mydb table=mydb_table usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=0
account    required     pam_mysql.so      verbose=1 user=mydbusername passwd=mydbpass host=localhost db=mydb table=mydb_table usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=0
```

My question is how to properly use **pam_mkhomedir** to create the directory with the username from mysql. I found this documentation https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/07/30/auto-creation-of-user-home-directories-in-linux/

I'm wondering if this is the proper configuration, I'd also like to know how he username is set for the directory. I do not see anywhere's in the code where username is applied, or is that something that just happens behind the scenes?

**Dynamic Directory Configuration Code**

```
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke 
auth       required     pam_mysql.so      verbose=1 user=mydbusername passwd=mydbpass host=localhost db=mydb table=mydb_table usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=0
account    required     pam_mysql.so      verbose=1 user=mydbusername passwd=mydbpass host=localhost db=mydb table=mydb_table usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password crypt=0
session    required     pam_mkhomedir.so  skel=/etc/ftp/ umask=0022
```

Answer (score 4):

```
session    required     pam_mkhomedir.so  skel=/etc/ftp/ umask=0022
```

As you can see, `pam_mkhomedir.so` acts at the *session* level. This means that it acts **after** the user has been authenticated (by the `auth` facility). To do so, it defines the following PAM-specific function :

```
PAM_EXTERN
int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t * pamh, int flags, 
                        int argc, const char **argv);
```

As I said, this function is called when the user has been authenticated. Therefore, when it retrieves the PAM user handle...

```
/* Determine the user name so we can get the home directory */
retval = pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_USER, (const void **)&user);
```

... it gets access to the name of an *authenticated*, existing user. With this information, the module will be able to retrieve what it needs (the path to a home directory) through a simple [`getpwnam(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) library call:

```
/* Get the password entry */
pwd = getpwnam(user);
```

This will return the following structure, filled with information about the user:

```
struct passwd {
    char   *pw_name;       /* username */
    char   *pw_passwd;     /* user password */
    uid_t   pw_uid;        /* user ID */
    gid_t   pw_gid;        /* group ID */
    char   *pw_gecos;      /* user information */
    char   *pw_dir;        /* home directory */
    char   *pw_shell;      /* shell program */
};
```

Now, if you wonder where this information is coming from, have a look at [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf). The [*Name Service Switch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) (NSS) is here to provide information regarding *names* in general (which can be usernames, aliases, groups, hosts, ... see [`nsswitch.conf(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf) for more details). If the guide you followed is complete enough, it should have had you configure both PAM **and** NSS: the first handles authentication and account/session management, while the other is merely here to provide name information. In other words, the first one can perform read/write operations, while the second one is read-only.

Once `pam_mkhomedir.so` has retrieved the path to the user's home directory, all it has to do is check whether or not it exists, and create it if it does not:

```
/* Stat the home directory, if something exists then we 
 * assume it is correct and return a success. */
if(stat(pwd->pw_dir, &st) == 0) return PAM_SUCCESS;

return create_homedir(..., pwd, ...);
```

The `create_homedir` function is defined by the module itself, and it is a  bit too long for me to paste it here. Just see it as a big [`mkdir(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) call, which handles specific cases and makes sure everything goes smoothly. If you're interested in more details, have a look at `pam_mkhomedir.so`'s source code. I used [this version of it](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pam/pam-9/pam/modules/pam_mkhomedir/pam_mkhomedir.c) for my answer (it was written by *Jason Gunthorpe*, whose name is also on [my `pam_mkhomedir.so` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mkhomedir)).

Now, as far as I'm concerned, I think the guide you followed is a little incomplete, or at least, [the MySQL table it has you create](http://centosforserver.blogspot.ca/2010/02/virtual-hosting-with-vsftpd-and-mysql.html) is:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(30) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| pass     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table is probably detailed enough for VSFTPd to work. Since it is configured with a home root, it can easily determine a user's home directory: `$ftp_root/username`. This is actually set with the `local_root` parameter:

```
local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
```

However, `pam_mkhomedir.so` is not VSFTPd. It doesn't use this mechanism, but relies on NSS (through [`getpwnam(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam)). The problem is: your MySQL table does not provide enough information for NSS to fill the `struct passwd` we saw earlier. In order to have NSS use MySQL as a source, you'll need to install [nss-mysql](http://libnss-mysql.sourceforge.net/), which requires a larger MySQL table. This will require adjustments in your VSFTPd configuration, but you should have no problem in having VSFTPd and nss-mysql cohabitate.

[This directory](http://libnss-mysql.sourceforge.net/libnss-mysql/sample/minimal/) gives an example for a minimal nss-mysql setup. The MySQL table for users is defined as follows:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username_canonical    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_canonical       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| enabled               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| salt                  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| locked                | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expired               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expires_at            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| confirmation_token    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password_requested_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| roles                 | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credentials_expired   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credentials_expire_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, you might not need all these fields yourself, but keep in mind that `struct passwd` structure we saw earlier, and make sure nss-mysql has enough data to fill it :) Besides, the nss-mysql configuration files are flexible enough for you to use default values for anything.